# rm is not working with []

Tags: wildcards, rm

I have files like:

```
ls CONFIG2
DOS      DOSCAR    KPOINTS  PCDAT   WAVECAR        submit_vasp_beskow.sh
CHG      EIGENVAL  OSZICAR  POSCAR  XDATCAR        vasprun.xml
CHGCAR   IBZKPT    OUT      POTCAR  error_file.e
CONTCAR  INCAR     OUTCAR   PROCAR  output_file.o
ls CONFIG2/DOS/
CHG      EIGENVAL  OSZICAR  POSCAR   error_file.e
CHGCAR   IBZKPT    OUT      POTCAR   output_file.o
CONTCAR  INCAR     OUTCAR   PROCAR   submit_vasp_beskow.sh
DOSCAR   KPOINTS   PCDAT    XDATCAR
```

I am trying to delete selected files from both the folders and I tried:

```
 rm -rvf CONFIG2[/DOS[/PROCAR, /CHG*, /vasprun.xml]]
```

ending up with error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'CONFIG2[/DOS[/PROCAR,': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/CHG*,': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/vasprun.xml]]': No such file or directory
```

Where I am going wrong here?

Comment: Which shell are you using `bash`, or other (`zsh`, `ksh` or other). Don't think the `bash` glob supports the format you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `{}`, not `[]`:

```
echo CONFIG2{,/DOS}/{PROCAR,CHG*,vasprun.xml}
```

You also mustn’t use spaces after the commas.